# run phpunit's tests within a cron job scheduler in laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit, tdd

i've searched google for a solution to run my **tests** (*unit and feature*) in **laravel** `kernel.php` , using scheduler. but i got no chance ,
can anyone please make a suggestion on this situation ?
scenario:
run my tests in `tests/` directory every day at `00:00` like:

```
 $schedule->call(function(){$this->runAllMyTests($please);})->dailyAt('00:00');
```

or (i know its like a joke but wishful to do like this ):

```
$schedule->call(function () {
   Artisan::call('./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter SubmitOrdetTest');
})->dailyAt('00:00');
```

the final purpose is to run tests every night and make a report of failed or successful tests so can send a report mail to someone ,
any suggestion would be pleasure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit is not an artisan command, but a php script and need to be executed from the command line or any other means.

use [Scheduling Shell Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling#scheduling-shell-commands)

```php
$schedule->exec('./vendor/bin/phpunit')->dailyAt('00:00');
```

Comment: missing this little pointing on the documentation , and also not appeared in my search results , however it worked m thank you,

Comment: is this type of running tests needs some sort of configurations ? , because when i run tests from kernel schedule , it deals with my origin db not test db

Comment: How are you setting up test configurations? if its with `phpunit.xml` everything should work as expected. You can do `->appendOutputTo(some-output-file-path')` with the schedule statement and inspect for any issues.

Comment: If nothing helps, you can pass the config file to the `phpunit` execution command with `-c <file>` or `--configuration <file>`.

`$schedule->exec('./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration <file>')->dailyAt('00:00');`